# How to make two same networkx graph have same node order

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have two networkx graph with same topology.
Their weisfeiler_lehman_graph_hash is same.
And is_isomorphic returns True.
But the node order of these two graphs are different.
So my question is How to reorder their nodes so that they can have the same node order.
Here is an simple example:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> import networkx.algorithms.graph_hashing as graph_hashing
>>> import networkx.algorithms.isomorphism as isomorph
>>> A = nx.Graph()
>>> B = nx.Graph()
>>> A.add_nodes_from([(4,{"elem":"N"}),(5,{"elem":"H"}),(6,{"elem":"C"})])
>>> A.add_edges_from([(5,6),(4,6)])
>>> B.add_nodes_from([(1,{"elem":"C"}),(2,{"elem":"N"}),(3,{"elem":"H"})])
>>> B.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3)])
>>> A.nodes.data()
NodeDataView({4: {'elem': 'N'}, 5: {'elem': 'H'}, 6: {'elem': 'C'}})
>>> B.nodes.data()
NodeDataView({1: {'elem': 'C'}, 2: {'elem': 'N'}, 3: {'elem': 'H'}}) 
#B have different node label and order from A
>>> isomorph.is_isomorphic(A,B)
True
>>> graph_hashing.weisfeiler_lehman_graph_hash(A,node_attr='elem')
'41951f5f6a37cdb32e7de9b6429fa0e9'
>>> graph_hashing.weisfeiler_lehman_graph_hash(B,node_attr='elem')
'41951f5f6a37cdb32e7de9b6429fa0e9'  
#B have same graph hash and is isomorphic to A
```

what I want is some function reorder_node_by()

```
>>> A.nodes.data()
NodeDataView({4: {'elem': 'N'}, 5: {'elem': 'H'}, 6: {'elem': 'C'}})
>>> B.nodes.data()
NodeDataView({1: {'elem': 'C'}, 2: {'elem': 'N'}, 3: {'elem': 'H'}}) 
>>> B.reorder_node_by(A)
>>> B.nodes.data()
NodeDataView({1: {'elem': 'N'}, 2: {'elem': 'H'}, 3: {'elem': 'C'}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VF2 Algorithm used in `is_isomorphic` has an extended interface, which you can get from its [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.vf2.html):

```
from networkx.algorithms import isomorphism
GM = isomorphism.GraphMatcher(B, A)
GM.is_isomorphic()
# True
GM.mapping
# {2: 4, 1: 6, 3: 5}
```

This you then need to combine with [`relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html):

```
B = nx.relabel_nodes(B, GM.mapping, copy=False)
```